# Labouchère system counting possible sequences of W\L given the number of plays $n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Suppose we have a game with probability for winning and for losing are $\frac{1}{2}$. We use [Labouchère system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labouch%C3%A8re_system) with starting numbers $(1,2,3,4)$.

> Note: this system goes like this: if win - wipe out first and last number of sequence you have. If lose -  add the sum of first and last number in the sequence to the end of the sequence.

And the question is:

> if we played $n$ times, how many possible sequences of W\L (Win\Lose) are they given that the number of plays was $n$?

I have no idea how to approach it directly so I started counting for some small $n$ to find any relation or formula for them.

- Firstly,  $n=1$.

It is clearly impossible, we need at least $2$ plays to end the Labouchère system.

- $n=2$

Now if we ended in exactly two plays, it means we won both times, so the only possible sequence is $(WW).$

- $n=3$

Again impossible.

- $n=4$

$$(WLWW), (LWWW) $$

- $n=5$

Here we have some more possibilities
$$(WLLWW), (WLWLW),  (LWWLW), (LWLWW), (LLWWW)  $$

- $n=6$

Again, nothing for $n=6$.

- $n=7$

**EDIT:** As @RossMillikan pointed I've missed some sequences in this case:
$$(WLWLLWW), (LWWLLWW), (WLLWLWW), (LWLWLWW), (LLLWWWW),(LLWWLWW), (LLWLWWW), (LWLLWWW), (WLLLWWW) $$

And so on...

So what we can conclude for now, we need to find function $f$, such that $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N_0}$ and:
$f(1)=0,$  $f(2)=1,$  $f(3)=0,$  $f(4)=2,$  $f(5)=5,$  $f(6)=0,$  $f(7)=9...$
Then we see that $$(\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) \quad f(3k)=0.$$

And more for sequences: for any $m$ such that $n>m$ there **can't** be a sequence for $n$ such that starts with any sequence which already appear in the $m$ case.

Comment: Case: $n=3k+2$: 

for $k=1$, we have $n=5$ and we need $3$ wins and $2$ loses, and by your assumptions we need $4$ wins and $1$ lose.

Comment: I confused myself.  For $n=3k+2n$ you need $k+2$ wins and $2k$ losses. For $n=3k+1$ you need $k+2$ wins and $2k−1$ losses. Then you need the losses early enough so you don't run out of numbers earlier. The last is the hard part to compute.  I am thinking the approach to the Catalan numbers may help, but not sure.

Comment: @RossMillikan may be you are right about Catalan number, but I don't really see how to use them here.

Comment: Nor do I or I would have answered.  I just thought about the version where you count ballots and one person is always ahead or tied.  Your problem is the same except one kind of ballot counts twice the other.

Comment: Second and sixth are not the same, if I understand you correctly. But you are right about some missing elements. Your second is actually my second in the $n=7$ case. @RossMillikan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=3k+1$ we must have $k+2$ wins and $2k-1$ losses.  For $n=3k+2$ we must have $k+2$ wins and $2k$ losses.  As you say, we can accept any ordering of wins and losses that does not have a prefix of a shorter acceptable list.  We can define $X(k)$ as the number of acceptable strings of length $3k+1$ and $Y(k)$ as the number of acceptable strings of length $3k+2$.  We can write a recursive computation for these.  We start with all strings with the right number of wins and losses, then subtract off the ones that start with a shorter string.  For example, with $k=2$ and computing $X(2)$ we start with ${7 \choose 3}=35$ strings that have four wins and three losses.  The string $WW$ that represents $Y(0)$ can be extended to our target composition in ${5 \choose 3}=10$ ways because we add two wins and three losses.  Each of the two strings that represents $X(1)$ can be extended in three ways because we have to add two losses and a win, so we lose six strings.  Each of the five strings that represents $Y(1)$ can be extended in two ways because we have to add one win and one loss, so we subtract $10$.  That leaves us with $X(2)=35-10-6-10=9$ strings.  The base case is $X(0)=0,Y(0)=1$, then the recurrences are $$X(k)={3k+1 \choose k+2}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}X(j){3(k-j) \choose k-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}Y(j){3(k-j)-1 \choose k-j}\\
Y(k)={3k+2 \choose k+2}-\sum_{j=0}^kX(j){3(k-j)+1 \choose k-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}Y(j){3(k-j) \choose k-j}$$
I implemented this in Python and find

$$\begin {array} {r r r r r}k&n&X(k)&n&Y(k)\\1&4&2&5&5\\2&7&9&8&23\\3&10&43&11&113\\4&13&218&14&585\\5&16&1155&17&3148\\6&19&6324&20&17442\\7&22&35511&23&98857\\8&25&203412&26&570515\\9&28&1184040&29&3341325\\10&31&6983925&32&19809465\\11&34&41652468&35&118657212\\12&37&250763464&38&717017228\\13&40&1521935948&41&4365748104\\14&43&9301989144&44&26758408510\\15&46&57203999295&47&1.64964E+11\\16&49&3.53702E+11&50&1.02225E+12\\17&52&2.1976E+12&53&6.36394E+12\\18&55&1.37133E+13&56&3.97823E+13\\19&58&8.59072E+13&59&2.49618E+14\\20&61&5.40072E+14&62&1.57156E+15 \end {array}$$
I didn't find these in OEIS